# WiX wxl file doesn't replace ProductTitleVersion

Tags: wix

here's my .wixproj:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
      ...
      <MSIProductTitleVersion Condition="'$(MSIProductTitleVersion)' == ''">1.1.1.1 (Staging)</MSIProductTitleVersion>
      ...          
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
      <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
      <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\Debug\</IntermediateOutputPath>
      <DefineConstants>
        Debug;CabName=$(MSICabName);ProductTitleVersion=$(MSIProductTitleVersion);ProductVersion=$(MSIProductVersion);Manufacturer=$(MSIManufacturer);ProductCode=$(MSIProductCode);UpgradeCode=$(MSIUpgradeCode);PackageCode=$(MSIPackageCode);
      </DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

wxl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WixLocalization Culture="en-us" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">
  <String Id="WelcomeDlgDescription">The Setup Wizard will install [ProductTitleVersion] on your computer. Click Next to continue or Cancel to exit the Setup Wizard.</String>
```

The end result is just a blank space in the installer dialog header.

Using `ProductVersion` works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so, this was it; in my `.wxs` file, I needed:

```
        <Property Id="ProductTitleVersion">$(var.ProductTitleVersion)</Property>
      </Product>
    </Wix>
```

I guess the `.wxs` then makes the `.wixproj` values available in the `.wxl` processing.